# Why am I getting a CSRF 403 from OAuth2 Proxy when running on GKE but not locally?

Tags: kubernetes, oauth, google-kubernetes-engine, openid-connect, oauth2-proxy

I have a simple setup that is using OAuth2 Proxy to handle authentication. It works fine locally using minikube but when I try to use GKE when the oauth callback happens I get a 403 status and the the following message...

> Login Failed: Unable to find a valid CSRF token. Please try again.

The offending url is `http://ourdomain.co/oauth2/callback?code=J_6ao0AxSBRn4bwr&state=r_aFqM9wsSpPvyKyyzE_nagGnpNKUp1pLyZafOEO0go%3A%2Fip`

What should be configured differently to avoid the CSRF error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case it was because I needed to set the cookie to `secure = false`. Apparently I could still have secure true no problem with http and an IP but once I uploaded with a domain it failed.

Comment: Are you refering to cookie-secure in oauth2 proxy env configuration?

I have done that still i am getting error